# Org mode edit timestamp with custom format

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I paste default timestamp and I can edit year, month, day, time with Shift-up and Shift-down

[image]

I want to use custom format

```
(setq-default org-display-custom-times t)
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats 
  '("<%d %b %Y %a" . "<%d %b %Y %a %H:%M>"))
```

But I can't edit year, month, time. Only day

[image]

What should I do to be able to edit year, month, time with Shift-up/down? I can't event select it

Answer (score 4):

The Org Manual is explaining the disadvantages of using custom timestamps here:

https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html#Custom-time-format

> The S-UP/DOWN keys can no longer be used to adjust each component of a timestamp. If the cursor is at the beginning of the stamp, S-UP/DOWN will change the stamp by one day, just like S-LEFT/RIGHT. At the end of the stamp, the time will be changed by one minute.

Does that not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can `C-c C-x C-t` to disable custom formats, edit your dates with `S-UP/DOWN` (or manually), and then do `C-c C-x C-t` to re-enable the custom format.